# Split a string via regex using lookahead

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to split this text:

```
September 1997, such and such
```

into:

```
September 1997
such and such
```

I need to split right after YYYY. How can I do it via a regex? This is my attempt:

```
"September 1997, such and
such".to_s.split(/\s+(?=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\,)/)
```

Output:

```
September
1997, such and such
```

Comment: You're over-thinking the problem, which is common with regular expressions. Try to keep them simple. If they deviate from that, odds are good you're doing something wrong, either in choosing to use a pattern, or in how you're using it. There are very complex patterns out there, where someone tried to remove a lot of the processing from their code and hand it off to the regex engine, but those patterns are almost unmaintainable, and are usually built in small pieces which are then assembled together to make the complex one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem with using only `,` in regex?

```
input = 'September 1997, such and such'
print input.split(/,/)
```

If you really need to use lookaround then this one:

```
input = 'September 1997, such and such'
print input.split(/(?<=\d\d\d\d)\s*,\s*/)
```

Comment: `\d\d\d\d` is equivalent to `\d{4}`

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you need a `regex` for this, the below is just a simple solution without regex, split by the `comma` and `space` except of course I don't understand what you want

```
"September 1997, such and such".split(", ") 
#=>["September 1997", "such and such"]
```